# How to update outputText value based on selected checkboxes in dataTable through ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need your help in updating an `outputText` with the total Amount field for the selected checkboxes in a dataTable. The jsf has the below code:

```
    <p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" selection="#{hrdirector.selectedRequests}"
             value="#{hrdirector.listPendingRequests}" rowKey="#{hr.requestNo}"
             filteredValue="#{hrdirector.filteredRequests}" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar">
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"></p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Request No.">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestNo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Request Amount">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestAmount}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <h:outputText id="Sum" value="#{hr.Sum}"/>
```

The user is going to select a number of checkboxes and I need to know the appropriate way to call a method through ajax to update the outputText with the Total Requests Amounts selected.

The method to be called is:

```
   public void ShowTotal() {


       try {

        String [] tranAmountArr = new String[selectedRequests.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRequests.size(); i++) {

            tranAmountArr[i] = selectedRequests.get(i).getEncashmentAmount();

            Sum = Sum + Double.parseDouble(tranAmountArr[i]);

        }

        System.out.println(Sum);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.print(e);

        e.printStackTrace();

        log.error("Error in ShowTotal()");

    }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20456143/1391249

Comment: @BalusC is a very elegant solution if you only need to output the sum. If you later want to do any validation or additional operation you will have to add server side listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add two Ajax tags inside your table:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{hrdirector.showTotal}" 
process="@this" update="sum" />
```

And:

```
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{hrdirector.showTotal}" 
process="@this" update="sum" />
```

Note: For method names, paremeters, attributtes and IDs use lowercase.

Note: I would name the method "updateTotal" instead "ShowTotal".

Comment: Thanks it worked. But instead of rowSelect/rowUnselect, I should use rowSelectCheckbox and rowUnselectCheckbox